# How can I use the same DNS challenge key another time in certbot?

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

I run

```
docker-compose run certbot -d *.domain1.com -d *.domain2.com --manual --preferred-challenges dns certonly
```

However when I press <kbd>enter</kbd> too early I get the following error

- The following errors were reported by the server:

  > Domain: domain1.com
  >   Type:   None
  >   Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up TXT for
  >   _acme-challenge.domain1.com

When running the command again I get new challenge keys. I would like to retry until my DNS record are "live" (DNS server is up to date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there is no way to renew a certificate by DNS challenge, without adding a new TXT record.

- https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/renewing-with-dns-challenge/37184
- https://serverfault.com/questions/879647/renew-domains-using-certbot-and-using-dns-challenge